# How read count is calculated across different queries with partially same result set?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Consider I have a Firestore query *query1* which returns 10 documents and another query *query2* which returns 15 documents, but this time out of 15, 5 documents are common for both *query1* and *query2*. So for the second query, is the read count 10 or 15 in a persistence enabled platform?

Comment: I think this article, [How to drastically reduce the number of reads when no documents are changed in Firestore?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-drastically-reduce-the-number-of-reads-when-no-documents-are-changed-in-firestore-8760e2f25e9e) might help.

Comment: @Alex I read that the day you wrote as I follow you on medium :-). I asked this question out of curiosity. I asked a different question on the same line here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69513140/will-this-approach-of-using-two-queries-reduce-firestore-read-count-work?noredirect=1#comment122867552_69513140

Comment: Thanks for following me. I hope @Renaud will be able to provide an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Persistence doesn't change anything while the app is online. Each query bills reads according to the number of documents that were retrieved from the server.  It doesn't matter if previously queried documents are in the cache -- all results from an online query always come from the server.

When the app is offline, queries will not bill reads, and only read from the cache. But your app doesn't know if this is the case.

The only way you can force a query not to bill document reads is if you instruct the query to only using a [source option](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/get-data#source_options) to force the query to use the local cache and not consult the server at all.

Also read:

- https://medium.com/firebase-developers/should-i-query-my-firebase-database-directly-or-use-cloud-functions-fbb3cd14118c
- https://medium.com/firebase-developers/firestore-clients-to-cache-or-not-to-cache-or-both-8f66a239c329

Comment: Waw this is completely opposite of what I thought about how firestore works all these years. I used to think if I call the `query2`  within 30mins of execution of `query1` and the result set is the same as `query1` then I won't be charged as the result is fulfilled via cache.  Is this not true?

Comment: It is not true. The cache is primarily to support cases where the app temporarily goes offline.

Comment: I am really confused. In another related question you answered like this - "If you get a single document using the default "source" (source options are "cache" or "server" or "default"), then the cache will be consulted first, and if it's fresh, then you get the document without billing." https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54191680/firestore-billing-for-reading-a-document-with-subcollections

Comment: That other answer was not correct.  I fixed it.