# Will this approach of using two queries reduce Firestore read count work?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection called `tasks` which contains more than 100 documents. App's home screen has a list view which shows a list of all the documents but this approach will unnecessarily cost 100 reads every time a user opens the app. So to stop that I added a field called `updated_at` to each document which I update every time user updates the task document. So now this is how I build the home screen.

```
 buildListView() async{
   //get locally stored latest updated_at
   const lastUpdatedAt = getLastUpdatedOfLatestFetchedDoc()
   await firestore.collection('tasks').where('updated_at', '>', lastUpdatedAt).get(source: 'server');
   const docs = await firestore.collection('tasks').get(source: 'cache');
  //Build list using docs array
 }
```

First query will get only those documents which are updated after the last fetch time from the server. 2nd query will fetch all the documents but from the cache. I don’t care about the result of the 1st query as it may or may not return any documents but if it returns it will anyway store in the cache which 2nd query will include.
Will this approach work?

Comment: It is not clear to me why you call twice the `get()` method with different `GetOptions` objects (`source: 'server'`and `source: 'cache'`). Maybe you forgot to delete one of the lines? Having said that, the approach of storing an `updated_at` value and querying based on this field is totally valid. You should use a Timestamp.

Comment: I updated the question for more clarity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, the approach should work assuming that you've enabled the disk cache.

It won't significantly reduce the number of document reads on the server however as Firestore already will read un-updated documents from the disk cache anyway if you don't explicitly tell it to get them from the server (as you do here).

I'd also strongly recommend using `onSnapshot()` to make the user experience smoother, as that pretty much does a more efficient version of your code:

1. It calls your callback with the documents from the local cache.
2. It checks with the server if there are any updated/new documents.
3. It calls your callback again, with the now updated documents from the local cache.

So you'll already be able to paint the data in step 1 here, which typically leads to a better user experience than waiting for the updated data to have loaded.

Comment: Thanks Frank but I am more confused now. Actually I had two doubts and asked it in two separate questions. In another question I got a contradicting answer from Doug where he told  “it doesn't matter if previously queried documents are in the cache -- all results from an online query always come from the server.” 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69512828/how-read-count-is-calculated-across-different-queries-with-partially-same-result

Comment: I saw that question and was confused too. It might be worth running a simple test and comparing the two approaches. No matter what though: using an `onSnapshot` listener is more likely to both reduce the reads and give a better user experience.

Comment: Ok Frank. Thanks for the insight as always

Comment: Doug's answer actually makes sense for a "regular" query - the query can't know which documents that match the query are already in the cache without first FETCHING THE DOCUMENTS TO KNOW WHICH ONES MATCH THE QUERY - in other words, you would have to query BOTH the cache AND the server AND compare to know that some were already in the cache - a lot of round-trips from server to client.  As you discovered, you *can* find which documents in the cache match a query - but that tells you little about what *other* documents on the server match.